# Rendering multiple HTML pages in Python Flask (Heroku) App

Tags: python, heroku, flask, jinja2, weasyprint

I am trying to serve multiple HTML Pages to a single page and then serve that final single page as a PDF. I have a total of 95 pages and I have already achieved this using the following stack;

1. Python/ Flask
2. WeasyPrint HTML to PDF Creator
3. Jinja Templating using include

   ```
   {% include 'page1.html' %}
   {% include 'page2.html' %}
   ...
   ...
   {% include 'page95.html' %}
   ```
4. Heroku deployment
5. gunicorn and nginx along side Flask in production

My problem is, the final page takes more than 80seconds to display as a PDF(i.e: the final html page containing 95 other html pages). And Heroku can maintain a connection only for 28-30 seconds. Is there any way I can speed up this process of serving the final PDF?

Will multi-threading help this? (I may have to read up on how to do this - not an expert) I already have this in my app

```
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

Apologies if I am using any unclear terms here.

Comment: Is it always the same? Cache the result and serve that. Or better, do it once and instead of using dynamically loading it, put it in a static path.

Comment: Unfortunately, each page has a dynamic image content...so its not always the same :(

Comment: Is there a reason for generating each page, compiling them into one and then converting that to PDF? Are you not allowed to generate the pdf directly? I just tested generating the PDF directly using `reportlab` and it is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Reportlab PLUS has the feature to convert html to pdf...i will have to re-write everything to reportlab format...but this might be the only way to go

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a few things, I think the best way to reduce the time is to simply use Reportlab and make PDF out of single pages. Then I will be using

> pyPDF2

to merge all those single pages into one single PDF file to download. I will mark this as the answer, if I am able to execute it successfully!